# Way to give context to a JSON.parse reviver?

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I am formatting data inside JSON Strings and I need to use my application context (like this.name etc.) INSIDE the reviver.

Code example of reviver:

```
formatReviver = function (key, value) {

 if(context.name === value)
 //do stuff

}
```

**But obviously THIS does not work inside the Reviver.
An idea I had is to use default values inside the parameter:**

```
formatReviver = function (key, value, context = window) {

 if(context.name === value)
 //do stuff

}
```

Comment: What is a reviver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead:

```
formatReviver = (key, value, context = window) => {

  if(context.name === value)
  //do stuff

}
```

This syntax preserves "this" (context) as opposed to the function keyword, which changes the `this` scope depending on how it's used.